# Can do data binding but can't use the data I fetched with GraphQL query inside te component

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have some GraphQL queries in my Angular app, I can show the result in the HTML with data binding, but I can't use it inside the component, I guess because of the strucutre of the data I fetched.
This is the query:

```
   export const GET_ACTIVITY =  gql`query GetActivity {
      getActivity(deviceId:"g6x"){
            activity
          }

}`;
```

and in the app.component.ts:

```
data: any

this.apollo.query({
      query: GET_ACTIVITY
    }).subscribe(({ data, loading }) => {

    this.data = data;
});
```

"activity" is supposed to be a string, I can show it in the app.component.html with {{data.getActivity.activity}} but when I try to use this.data.getActivity.activity in the app.compinent.ts is an empty string (averything happens on ngOnInit). Why is it like that?

Comment: Everything needs to be inside the subscription.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but everything like what?

Comment: Any statement that directly depends on the async variable assigned inside the subscription should be inside the subscription as well.